# ASP.NET MVC Notification - Decrease the Total Number When the Notification is Clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, notifications

I am new in MVC. I do something about the notification thing. The design of the notification part is as follows and I list all notifications in this window:

[My Notification Window's Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnpZF.jpg)

I want to reduce the total number of notifications found above when I click on a notification in this window. For example:

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwdsy.jpg)

**KulNotBildirimPartial.cshtml:**

```
@model List<NoteModel>

<li class="dropdown dropdown-extended dropdown-notification" id="header_notification_bar">
<a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
    <i class="icon-bell"></i>
    <span class="badge badge-default">@(Model.Where(d=>d.DateSeen==null).Count())</span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="external">
        <h3>
            <span class="bold">Notifications</span>
        </h3>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Note", new { IsUserNotificationList = true })">View All</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu-list scroller" style="height: 250px;" data-handle-color="#637283">
            <li>
                @foreach (var item in Model.ToList())
                {
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Detail", "Note", new { IsUserNotificationList = true, ID = item.NoteID })">
                        <span class="details">
                            You have a note from the user
                            @(item.RelatedUserNameSurname)
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <span class="label label-sm label-default">@((item.AddDate).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"))</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                }
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller:**

```
[Login]
    public PartialViewResult UserNoteNotificationPartial()
    {
        tbl_User user = Functions.GetUser();
        List<NoteNotificationModel> notenotification = Constants.NoteModel.Where(d => d.RelatedUserID == user.ID && d.NoteID != d.NoteID).ToList();
        var AddNotification = db.tbl_NoteUserRelation.Where(d => d.RelatedUserID == user.ID).ToList();

        if (notenotification.Count > 0)
            AddNotification = AddNotification.Where(d => !notenotification.Any(n => n.NoteID == d.tbl_Note.ID)).ToList();

        List<NoteNotificationModel> All = AddNotification.Select(d => new NoteNotificationModel
        {
            Name = d.tbl_Note.Name,
            Content = d.tbl_Note.Content,
            AddDate = d.tbl_Note.AddDate,
            UserWhoAddetItID = d.tbl_Note.UserWhoAddetItID,
            RelatedUserNameSurname = (d.tbl_Note.tbl_User.Name + " " + d.tbl_Note.tbl_User.Surname),
            RelatedUserID = d.tbl_Note.tbl_User.ID,
            NoteID = d.NoteID,
            DateSeen=d.DateSeen,
        }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in All.ToList())
        {
            notenotification.Add(item);
        }
        Constants.NoteModel = notenotification.ToList();

        return PartialView(notenotification.OrderByDescending(d=>d.AddDate).ToList());
    }
```

How can I do that in the easiest way? If there is any other code block you want to insert, please tell me.

Comment: It is very bad practice to name your properties in a language other than English (is this Turkish?). I would love to help you but I don't even know where to begin right now.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your reply. The codes were arranged in English. You can check now if you want. Thank you even if you can't help.